# checkbox view data and on change based on dropdown list

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to view checkbox as id of category and depend on dropdown select can some one help me

the dropdown select is worked well but the onchange dos not work and if i get the sub category that depends on select category how insert multi checkbox in mysql database

'
my view is

```
  echo '<div class="control-group">';
    echo '<label for="category_id" class="control-label">category</label>';
    echo '<div class="controls">';
      //echo form_dropdown('category_id', $options_category, '', 'class="span2"');
      $js = 'id="category_sub" onChange="some_function();"';
      echo form_dropdown('category_id', $options_category, set_value('category_id'), 'class="span2" id="category_id"',$js);

    echo '</div>';
  echo '</div">';

  if( isset($_POST['category_id']) != ''){echo '<div class="control-group" id="category_sub"></div>';
  foreach ($services as $row){ 
$id = $row['ID']      ;   $options_sub_category = $row['Name_En'];

     // echo $options_sub_category ;
     //echo form_checkbox($options_sub_category, $options_sub_category, TRUE, 'class="span2" id="services"');
echo '<input type ="checkbox" name="services" id ="services" value="'. echo $id .'"> '. echo $options_sub_category ; .'';           

 }
  }
```

my controler is

public function add()
{

```
if(isset($_POST['category_id']) && $this->input->post('category_id')!=null){
    $id = $this->input->post('category_id');

$data ['services']  = $this->service_model->get_services($id);
}
//if save button was clicked, get the data sent via post

//fetch categorys data to populate the select field
$data['categorys'] = $this->category_model->get_category();


//load the view
$data['main_content'] = 'admin/company/add';
$this->load->view('includes/template', $data);  }
```

my model is

public function get_services($id) {

```
$this->db->select('*');

$this->db->where('category_id', $id);
$this->db->from('service');


$query = $this->db->get();

return $query->result_array();  }
```

Comment: the value get from



 foreach ($services as $row)
      { 
   $options_sub_category[$row['ID']] = $row['Name_Ar'];
      }

Comment: please share complete code

Comment: what are you passing in  $options_sub_category variable? Are you passing array in $options_sub_category ?

Comment: yep  passing array

Answer (score 0):

dropdown is a list box which can take more then one value.

```
echo form_dropdown('category_id', $options_category, '', 'class="span2"');
```

create a single dropdown with many list values.

```
form_checkbox()
```

creates single checkbox at a time. so instead of $options_sub_category array, use its value in the function like :

```
echo form_checkbox('services',  $value, TRUE, 'class="span2"');
```

please change $value as your variable name.

Comment: but i want to save multi checkbox and the value it same

foreach ($services as $row)
      { 
   $options_sub_category[$row['ID']] = $row['Name_Ar'];
}

Comment: look to the  answer 2 this is my cod can you help me